# Apache (ab): mod_fcgid 4x slower than mod_cgi

Tags: c, apache, fastcgi, httpd.conf, mod-fcgid

modules for:  regular cgi + fast cgi

```
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so
```

test folder for regular and fast cgi.

```
DocumentRoot "/test"

<Directory "/test/rc">
    Require all granted
    Options +ExecCGI
    SetHandler cgi-script
</Directory>


<Directory "/test/fc">
    Require all granted
    Options +ExecCGI
    SetHandler fcgid-script
</Directory>
```

C test scripts : regular cgi + fast cgi  ( named: 1.c )

Regular cgi:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("Content-Type: text/plain;\n\n");
  printf("ttt\n\n");
  return 0;
}
```

fcgi ( Fast Cgi )

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcgi_stdio.h>

int main(void) {
while (FCGI_Accept() >= 0) { 
  printf("Content-Type: text/plain;\n\n");
  printf("ttt\n\n");
  return 0;
}
}
```

Benchmark with regular cgi: ( **3.61 seconds** )

```
 ab -n 10 -c 10 http://<ip>/rc/1
 Time taken for tests:   3.613 seconds
```

Benchmark with fast cgi : ( **13.23 seconds** )

```
 ab -n 10 -c 10 http://<ip>/fc/1
 Time taken for tests:   13.233 seconds
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're supposed to call `FCGI_Finish()` instead of `return 0;`, otherwise your program just serves only *one* request before exiting.